# Short layover in CDG between Morocco and Israel

Tags: transit, israel, layovers, morocco, cdg

I have a EasyJet flight from Marrakech (Morocco) to Paris CDG.

2H15 later I have an El Al flight to Tel Aviv.

It is my understanding (would love some confirmation) that I cannot checkin my luggages directly to Tel Aviv, and that I will have to re-check-in in CDG.

Will I have enough time?

The alternative is to spend the night in Paris and take flight the next day, but less convenient of course...

Comment: You are correct about luggage. With easyJet's point to point model, you can't check your luggage directly to anywhere else (even if the second flight would also be operated by easyJet!).

Answer (score 9):

Indeed, you cannot check in your luggage in Marrakech directly to Tel-Aviv. You have to recover it at Paris CDG and check it in again. In theory it could work, but if you want to be on the safe side, spend the night in Paris. There are some not too expensive hotels around (Campanile, Etap, ...). Or look for an alternative routing.

There are two bottlenecks in your plan. The Easyjet plane will fly CDG-RAK-CDG. You have to pray that the Moroccan authorities and handling agents are doing a good job and process the plane on time. And everything has to work smoothly in CDG! My personal transit experience in CDG is far from being first-rate ... The second bottleneck can be the special El-Al checkin procedures. They ask the passengers to show up [three hours in advance](http://www.elal.co.il/ELAL/English/AllAboutYourFlight/AtTheAirport/CheckInTimes.htm) and they close the checkin gates [one hour before departure of the flight](http://www.elal.co.il/ELAL/English/AllAboutYourFlight/AtTheAirport/CheckInTimes.htm).